# Clarification regarding Joomla Access Control (ACL)

Tags: joomla, access-control

Consider following scenario in Joomla user access.

I have two users; **User1** and **User2**.

**User1** mapped to **Group1** and **User2** mapped to **Group2**. Also, **Group1** is mapped to View **Level1**.

[image]

For **Article1**, i set Edit, Delete permission as **Allowed** for **Group1** (permission for all other groups as **Denied**) and View access level is set to **Level1**

So, It should let User2 to edit Article1 and User1 to view article.

1. Since User2 can edit will he be able to view article as well ?
2. Is there anyway of controlling Joomla article access per user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing is that "seeing" and "doing" are treated separately. So one place you can make a mistake is to give a user an action permission on something she can't see. On the other hand. You need to add user2 to Group 1 either directly or by inheritance i.e. make group2 inherit from group1. You could also add Group 2 to access level 1.

To control by user in the implementation in the CMS you  would need to make a group that only contained that user.  The only exception is "edit own."

However with plugins or with your own implementation of acl using JAccess you have the possibility to do many other approaches.

Comment: Any extension to do those ?

Comment: To do which part? You should really just use the core user manager if possible and the use case you describe is very run of the mill.